# Imagen en base64 por Webservice

Tags: android, json

¿Está bien cargar una imagen codificada en base64 por un servicio REST?
cargo los datos de un negocio y mando la imagen de ese negocio ya en base64 aunque no se si sea buena práctica realizarlo así, quiero saber si estoy haciendo bien, y de no serlo ¿Cómo mandar una imagen de mi servidor al cliente? los datos se consumirán en Android y el servicio está realizado en PHP.

JSON

```
{
"IDNEGOCIO":18,
"IDCATEGORIA":15,
"NOMBRENEGOCIO":"PIZZAS ANGGELOTI",
"IMAGEN":"\/93453453453453433SDFDSD8FSD7F8SD7F7SD9F8S89F..."
}
```

Comment: Estás recibiendo o enviando hacia tu servidor ?

Comment: Recibiendo el JSON desde el servidor

Comment: Si estás recibiendo sólo debes obtener la ruta de la imagen y luego setear la imagen en un ImageView por ejemplo.. bueno yo utilizo **Glide** `Glide.with(context)
                .load(rutaIcono)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imageView);`

Comment: o sea que tu precargas las imágienes en los recursos de la app?

Comment: No te confundas no lo guardo en recurso. **Glide** guarda la imagen en caché, claro definiéndolo. Por que existen tipos de guardados https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo de dos factores:

1) Si no te importa que tu imagen sea visible desde un navegador puedes poner esa imagen en una URL, y en el JSON obtienes la URL, posteriormente puedes poner en un ImageView cuando lo necesites esa imagen. Guardándola en caché.

2) Si no quieres que sean visibles y sean más privadas lo puedes hacer en base64 y después decodificarlo en el dispositivo.

Otra opción es obteniendola mediante sockect con un servidor, pero viendo para qué la quieres, esta opción no viene mucho al tema.